# Indentation in inparaenum

Tags: paralist, tabto

```
  \documentclass{article}
  % class can be a book, twoside. difference is in the layouts
  \usepackage{paralist}
  \usepackage{tabto}
  \usepackage[a4paper,left=2.8cm,right=2.8cm,top=2.8cm,bottom=3cm,]{geometry}

  \begin{document}

  \flushleft

  \begin{inparaenum}
  \setcounter{enumi}{20}
   \parbox{\textwidth}{
   \item  Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question QuesQuestion Question Question Question Question Question Question Question QuPassage Passage Passage Passage Passage Passage Passagestion Que Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question  \\ 
  \NumTabs{4}  \begin{inparaenum}[(a)]
   \item  None of the above.xyz
  \tab \item  None of the above.xyz 
  \tab \item None of the a Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option Option 
  \tab \item None of the above.xyzfgchvjbknm
  \end{inparaenum} }
   ~\\ ~\\ 
   \end{inparaenum}


  \end{document}
```

What I am getting in pdf:

[image: actual output]

But what I want is : (See difference in option c)

[image: expected output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is the horizontal spacing between item `(a)` and item `(b)` wanted?

Comment: Yes. They should appear like a tab. If length of the options is small, all 4 options will come in a single line. And if the length increases, number of tabs change to 2 from 4. And if increases more, it becomes 1 options per line.

Comment: That is easy to do with the `tasks` or the `shortlst` package.